# Ideas on simulating webservices for local automated testing

Tags: testing, networking, simulation, web-services

I am testing an app, which talks to different webservices over the internet.
For my automated testing, I don't want to go over the network.
To achieve this, I need to simulate the webservice on my machine using another app.
My initial thought is to record all the requests and responses between client and webservice, 
and then just write a simulation app which replays these responses.
The disadvantage here is that everytime the webservice protocol changes a bit, I have to modify all my recorded resposnes.
so I am looking to see if there are more elegant solutions.

have anyone solved a similar problem? any thoughts, suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: What platform are you using? .NET? Java? It matters because a WCF service can be hosted anywhere - including within a unit test. You could create a mock service that would run inside your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to "mock" those external dependencies. [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/gettingstarted/mocking.html) is one good solution for this.